# How to inject an async service into a singleton Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I had the following Middleware, the main idea is that check for every request (throught View or Ajax) if the user is not blocked in the database.

```
internal class UserMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly IUsuariosRepository userRepository;

        public UserMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IUsuariosRepository userRepository)
        {
            this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            this.userRepository = userRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepository));
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
                           string guid = httpContext.User.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("theClaimGuid"))?.Value;
            bool isBlocked = await userRepository.CheckUserBlockByGUID(guid);

            if (isBlocked)
            {
             await  httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("You are blocked.");
                return;
            }

            await next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

The call to the database with the context is made in the `CheckUserBlockByGUID` method:

```
public class UsuariosRepository : IUsuariosRepository
{
    private readonly nContext _context;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public UsuariosRepository(nContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _context = context;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }


    public async Task<bool> CheckUserBlockByGUID(string guid) {
       bool isOK = await _context.Usuarios.Where(u => u.Guid == guid && u.Deleted == 0 && u.blocked == 0).AnyAsync();
        return !isOK;
    }

     ...
```

and the `Middleware` is called inside `Startup.cs` / `Config` as:

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMiddleware<UserMiddleware>();
```

All my calls to the database are used with `async` / `await` but with this one, I get the following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation
> completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same
> instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading
> issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

I understand that I'm calling without waiting for the close operation of the other one. But I can't find that call. I don't know even if the error is this one or the problem is another one that I'm not seeing right now.

Any help or tip will be preciated.
Also please ask me in order to clarify this question or update it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Middleware is constructed just once. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0#per-request-middleware-dependencies

Comment: @IanMercer Im pretty new in Core, coming from Framework. Sorry for my ignorance. What you mean is that middleware doesn't work in order to check every petition?

Comment: It should work if your IUserRepository is scoped to a request, and it is received as parameter of InvokeAsync, not as constructor argument, as stated in the link provided by @IanMercer

Comment: @jbl thanks for your comment. Right now I'm pretty far away to understand it but I will keep trying to identify the differences.

Comment: @IanMercer perfect, I could it work it. Could you please write it as answer so I upvote and accept it? Thanks